# Run Octave (ver 4.0.0) from within Emacs (25.0.50)

Tags: emacs, octave

I load a .m file into emacs.

When I do (alt x + run-octave) I get the message:"process Inferior Octave exited abnormally with code 57.

I added to the .emacs the lines "(autoload 'octave-mode "octave-mod" nil t)
(setq auto-mode-alist
      (cons '("\.m$" . octave-mode) auto-mode-alist))", per the suggestion of " https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Running-Octave-from-Within-Emacs.html",
 but, It did not make any differnce.

How should I set-up emacs, so that I will be able to run octave on it's .m files?

Comment: Does the same thing happen with `emacs -Q`? Mine works fine on Emacs 25.0.50.1 and Octave 3.8.1.

Comment: Yes, It does come up with the same error message.Also, with the addition of -q the emacs does not recognize file with .m extension as an Octave file and it's tool bar shows Objc.